# django models/admin issue - admin displays table twice

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-admin

We moved a django model from one app to another ("PollRunForJira" was moved from "reports" to "jira_fat").

All the code seems clean from the old model and the django_migrations DB table is clean from the old model too.

Still the django admin display the 2 models:
[image]

Here's the new-model's admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin  
from jira_fat.models import PollRunForJira

@admin.register(PollRunForJira)
class RunJiraAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [f.name for f in PollRunForJira._meta.fields]
    search_fields = [f.name for f in PollRunForJira._meta.fields]
```

Here's the stack-trace when trying to access the old's model admin page:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/reports/pollrunforjira/
relation "fat_poll_run_for_jira" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "fat_poll_run_for_jira"
                                          ^
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://vd-yanayt:8000/admin/reports/pollrunforjira/
Django Version: 1.10.4
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "fat_poll_run_for_jira" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "fat_poll_run_for_jira"
                                          ^
Exception Location: /home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute, line 64
Python Executable:  /home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
['/home/yanayt/dev/fat/fatsite/run',
 '/home/yanayt/dev/fat/fatsite',
 '/home/yanayt/dev/fat/fatsite',
 '/home/yanayt/dev/gitlab-fw',
 '/home/yanayt/dev/fat',
 '/home/yanayt/dev/gitlab-fw/modules',
 '/home/yanayt/dev/fat/tests_and_pocs/neural_project',
 '/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib64/python27.zip',
 '/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib64/python2.7',
 '/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib64/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 9 Mar 2017 08:25:11 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py in wrapper
                return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in _wrapped_view
                    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py in _wrapped_view_func
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py in inner
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in _wrapper
            return bound_func(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in _wrapped_view
                    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in bound_func
                return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py in changelist_view
                self.list_max_show_all, self.list_editable, self, ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py in __init__
        self.get_results(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py in get_results
        result_count = paginator.count ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py in count
            return self.object_list.count() ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in count
        return self.query.get_count(using=self.db) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in get_count
        number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count'] ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in get_aggregation
        result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql
            cursor.execute(sql, params) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute
            return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py in __exit__
                six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) ...
▶ Local vars
Request information

USER
ramia
GET
No GET data
POST
No POST data
FILES
No FILES data
COOKIES
Variable    Value
csrftoken   
'V9GLLP65GqsOtO3BIaD2gcEzVC2FWR1bHbOTnOLGoYpEnImHfaZuAyurnSJ9TDPJ'
sessionid   
'tadzkbmrwyl3ifymz8mwmpzl2vntxwl6'
META
Variable    Value
CONTENT_LENGTH  
''
CONTENT_TYPE    
'text/plain'
CSRF_COOKIE 
'V9GLLP65GqsOtO3BIaD2gcEzVC2FWR1bHbOTnOLGoYpEnImHfaZuAyurnSJ9TDPJ'
CVS_RSH 
'ssh'
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS    
'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-k3hJr68Azw,guid=1044caba22e2b060c5fcd9ce58b57f82'
DESKTOP_SESSION 
'gnome-classic'
DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID  
'nautilus-5335-vd-yanayt.xiolab.lab.emc.com-/home/yanayt/pycharm-2016.1.4/bin/pycharm.sh-1_TIME359902'
DISPLAY 
':1.0'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE  
'config.settings'
DJ_DEBUG    
'true'
EDITOR  
'vim'
ESDAUTH 
'/var/opt/thinlinc/sessions/yanayt/1/esd_auth'
ESPEAKER    
'127.0.0.1:4910'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   
'CGI/1.1'
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE   
'/home/yanayt/Desktop/PC.desktop'
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID   
'6435'
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID    
'this-is-deprecated'
GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE    
'classic'
GPG_AGENT_INFO  
'/run/user/1418/keyring/gpg:0:1'
HISTCONTROL 
'ignoredups:erasedups'
HISTSIZE    
'1000'
HOME    
'/home/yanayt'
HOSTNAME    
'vd-yanayt.xiolab.lab.emc.com'
HTTP_ACCEPT 
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
'gzip, deflate, sdch'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
'en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6'
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL  
'max-age=0'
HTTP_CONNECTION 
'keep-alive'
HTTP_COOKIE 
'csrftoken=V9GLLP65GqsOtO3BIaD2gcEzVC2FWR1bHbOTnOLGoYpEnImHfaZuAyurnSJ9TDPJ; sessionid=tadzkbmrwyl3ifymz8mwmpzl2vntxwl6'
HTTP_HOST   
'vd-yanayt:8000'
HTTP_REFERER    
'http://vd-yanayt:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/reports/pollrunforjira/'
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  
'1'
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'
KDEDIRS 
'/usr'
KRB5CCNAME  
'/var/opt/thinlinc/sessions/yanayt/1/krb5cc'
LANG    
'en_US.UTF-8'
LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
'/home/yanayt/pycharm-2016.1.4/bin:/opt/thinlinc/lib64:/opt/thinlinc/lib'
LESSOPEN    
'||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s'
LOGNAME 
'yanayt'
MAIL    
'/var/spool/mail/yanayt'
NLSPATH 
'/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat'
PATH    
'/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/thinlinc/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/dt/bin:/usr/openwin/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/home/yanayt/bin'
PATH_INFO   
u'/admin/reports/pollrunforjira/'
PCSCTUN_COOKIE  
'/var/opt/thinlinc/sessions/yanayt/1/pcsctun-cookie'
PCSCTUN_SERVER  
'127.0.0.1:4916'
PULSE_COOKIE    
'/var/opt/thinlinc/sessions/yanayt/1/pulse-cookie'
PULSE_SERVER    
'127.0.0.1:4915'
PWD 
'/home/yanayt'
PYCHARM_HOSTED  
'1'
PYTHONIOENCODING    
'UTF-8'
PYTHONPATH  
'/home/yanayt/dev/fat/fatsite:/home/yanayt/dev/gitlab-fw:/home/yanayt/dev/fat:/home/yanayt/dev/gitlab-fw/modules:/home/yanayt/dev/fat/tests_and_pocs/neural_project'
PYTHONUNBUFFERED    
'1'
QTDIR   
'/usr/lib64/qt-3.3'
QTINC   
'/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include'
QTLIB   
'/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/lib'
QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM_CHECKED   
'1'
QT_IM_MODULE    
'ibus'
QT_PLUGIN_PATH  
'/usr/lib64/kde4/plugins:/usr/lib/kde4/plugins'
QUERY_STRING    
''
REMOTE_ADDR 
'10.76.50.168'
REMOTE_HOST 
''
REQUEST_METHOD  
'GET'
RUN_MAIN    
'true'
SCRIPT_NAME 
u''
SERVER_NAME 
'vd-yanayt.xiolab.lab.emc.com'
SERVER_PORT 
'8000'
SERVER_PROTOCOL 
'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE 
'WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.5'
SESSION_MANAGER 
'local/unix:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/5162,unix/unix:/tmp/.ICE-unix/5162'
SHELL   
'/bin/bash'
SHLVL   
'2'
SSH_ASKPASS 
'/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass'
SSH_AUTH_SOCK   
'/run/user/1418/keyring/ssh'
TLPREFIX    
'/opt/thinlinc'
TLPROFILE   
'gnome-classic'
TLSESSIONDATA   
'/var/opt/thinlinc/sessions/yanayt/1'
TOWN    
'Springfield'
TZ  
'UTC'
USER    
'yanayt'
USERNAME    
'yanayt'
VIRTUAL_ENV 
'/home/yanayt/envs/py2.7'
XAUTHORITY  
'/var/opt/thinlinc/sessions/yanayt/1/Xauthority'
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP 
'GNOME-Classic:GNOME'
XDG_MENU_PREFIX 
'gnome-'
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR 
'/run/user/1418'
XDG_SESSION_CLASS   
'user'
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP 
'gnome-classic'
XDG_SESSION_ID  
'6'
XDG_SESSION_TYPE    
'x11'
XFILESEARCHPATH 
'/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt'
XMODIFIERS  
'@im=ibus'
_   
'/home/yanayt/pycharm-2016.1.4/bin/../jre/jre/bin/java'
wsgi.errors 
<open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x7fe3940171e0>
wsgi.file_wrapper   
''
wsgi.input  
<socket._fileobject object at 0x7fe362dfd6d0>
wsgi.multiprocess   
False
wsgi.multithread    
True
wsgi.run_once   
False
wsgi.url_scheme 
'http'
wsgi.version    
(1, 0)
Settings
Using settings module config.settings
Setting Value
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES  
{}
ADMINS  
[]
ALLOWED_HOSTS   
['*']
APPEND_SLASH    
True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS 
('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
 'auth_fat.fat_ldap.LDAPBackendLAB',
 'auth_fat.fat_ldap.LDAPBackendCORP')
AUTH_LDAP_CORP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER   
True
AUTH_LDAP_CORP_SERVER_URI   
'ldap://corpishz2.corp.emc.com'
AUTH_LDAP_CORP_USER_ATTR_MAP    
{'email': 'mail', 'first_name': 'givenName', 'last_name': 'sn'}
AUTH_LDAP_CORP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE 
'corp\\%(user)s'
AUTH_LDAP_CORP_USER_SEARCH  
<django_auth_ldap.config.LDAPSearchUnion object at 0x1d9da90>
AUTH_LDAP_LAB_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER    
True
AUTH_LDAP_LAB_BIND_DN   
'uid=xiolabit1,cn=config'
AUTH_LDAP_LAB_BIND_PASSWORD 
u'********************'
AUTH_LDAP_LAB_SERVER_URI    
'ldap://ldap.xioeng.lab.emc.com'
AUTH_LDAP_LAB_USER_ATTR_MAP 
{'email': 'mail', 'first_name': 'givenName', 'last_name': 'sn'}
AUTH_LDAP_LAB_USER_SEARCH   
<django_auth_ldap.config.LDAPSearchUnion object at 0x1d9d950>
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS    
u'********************'
AUTH_USER_MODEL 
u'auth.User'
BASE_DIR    
'/home/yanayt/dev/fat/fatsite'
CACHES  
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
             'LOCATION': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0',
             'OPTIONS': {'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient'}}}
CACHE_BACKEND   
'redis_cache.cache://localhost:6379'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  
u'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX 
u'********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    
600
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE 
31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    
u'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH    
u'/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   
u'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME    
u'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS    
[]
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
             'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
             'NAME': 'fat_ng_db',
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': u'********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,
             'USER': 'xadmin'}}
DATABASE_ROUTERS    
[]
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS   
1000
DATETIME_FORMAT 
u'N j, Y, P'
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
[u'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
 u'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
 u'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
 u'%Y-%m-%d',
 u'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
 u'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 u'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
 u'%m/%d/%Y',
 u'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
 u'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 u'%m/%d/%y %H:%M',
 u'%m/%d/%y']
DATE_FORMAT 
u'N j, Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS  
[u'%Y-%m-%d',
 u'%m/%d/%Y',
 u'%m/%d/%y',
 u'%b %d %Y',
 u'%b %d, %Y',
 u'%d %b %Y',
 u'%d %b, %Y',
 u'%B %d %Y',
 u'%B %d, %Y',
 u'%d %B %Y',
 u'%d %B, %Y']
DATE_TIME_FORMAT    
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
DEBUG   
True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS  
False
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR   
u'.'
DEFAULT_CHARSET 
u'utf-8'
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE    
u'text/html'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER   
u'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    
u'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  
u'webmaster@localhost'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE    
u''
DEFAULT_LOG_PATH    
'/var/log/fat/fat-log.txt'
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  
u''
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS  
[]
EMAIL_BACKEND   
u'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST  
u'localhost'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD 
u'********************'
EMAIL_HOST_USER 
u''
EMAIL_PORT  
25
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE  
None
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE   
u'********************'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX    
u'[Django] '
EMAIL_TIMEOUT   
None
EMAIL_USE_SSL   
False
EMAIL_USE_TLS   
False
FILE_CHARSET    
u'utf-8'
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS   
None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    
[u'django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 u'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS 
None
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    
None
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK   
0
FIXTURE_DIRS    
[]
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME   
None
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH  
None
IGNORABLE_404_URLS  
[]
INSTALLED_APPS  
['redis_cache',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'fixture_magic',
 'auth_fat',
 'api',
 'client',
 'main_pages',
 'dir_listener',
 'analysis_retention',
 'run',
 'activities',
 'original_log',
 'reports',
 'jira_fat',
 'django_rq',
 'django_rq_dashboard',
 'scheduler',
 'daterange_filter']
INTERNAL_IPS    
[]
IS_DEBUG_TOOLBAR    
False
LANGUAGES   
[(u'af', u'Afrikaans'),
 (u'ar', u'Arabic'),
 (u'ast', u'Asturian'),
 (u'az', u'Azerbaijani'),
 (u'bg', u'Bulgarian'),
 (u'be', u'Belarusian'),
 (u'bn', u'Bengali'),
 (u'br', u'Breton'),
 (u'bs', u'Bosnian'),
 (u'ca', u'Catalan'),
 (u'cs', u'Czech'),
 (u'cy', u'Welsh'),
 (u'da', u'Danish'),
 (u'de', u'German'),
 (u'dsb', u'Lower Sorbian'),
 (u'el', u'Greek'),
 (u'en', u'English'),
 (u'en-au', u'Australian English'),
 (u'en-gb', u'British English'),
 (u'eo', u'Esperanto'),
 (u'es', u'Spanish'),
 (u'es-ar', u'Argentinian Spanish'),
 (u'es-co', u'Colombian Spanish'),
 (u'es-mx', u'Mexican Spanish'),
 (u'es-ni', u'Nicaraguan Spanish'),
 (u'es-ve', u'Venezuelan Spanish'),
 (u'et', u'Estonian'),
 (u'eu', u'Basque'),
 (u'fa', u'Persian'),
 (u'fi', u'Finnish'),
 (u'fr', u'French'),
 (u'fy', u'Frisian'),
 (u'ga', u'Irish'),
 (u'gd', u'Scottish Gaelic'),
 (u'gl', u'Galician'),
 (u'he', u'Hebrew'),
 (u'hi', u'Hindi'),
 (u'hr', u'Croatian'),
 (u'hsb', u'Upper Sorbian'),
 (u'hu', u'Hungarian'),
 (u'ia', u'Interlingua'),
 (u'id', u'Indonesian'),
 (u'io', u'Ido'),
 (u'is', u'Icelandic'),
 (u'it', u'Italian'),
 (u'ja', u'Japanese'),
 (u'ka', u'Georgian'),
 (u'kk', u'Kazakh'),
 (u'km', u'Khmer'),
 (u'kn', u'Kannada'),
 (u'ko', u'Korean'),
 (u'lb', u'Luxembourgish'),
 (u'lt', u'Lithuanian'),
 (u'lv', u'Latvian'),
 (u'mk', u'Macedonian'),
 (u'ml', u'Malayalam'),
 (u'mn', u'Mongolian'),
 (u'mr', u'Marathi'),
 (u'my', u'Burmese'),
 (u'nb', u'Norwegian Bokm\xe5l'),
 (u'ne', u'Nepali'),
 (u'nl', u'Dutch'),
 (u'nn', u'Norwegian Nynorsk'),
 (u'os', u'Ossetic'),
 (u'pa', u'Punjabi'),
 (u'pl', u'Polish'),
 (u'pt', u'Portuguese'),
 (u'pt-br', u'Brazilian Portuguese'),
 (u'ro', u'Romanian'),
 (u'ru', u'Russian'),
 (u'sk', u'Slovak'),
 (u'sl', u'Slovenian'),
 (u'sq', u'Albanian'),
 (u'sr', u'Serbian'),
 (u'sr-latn', u'Serbian Latin'),
 (u'sv', u'Swedish'),
 (u'sw', u'Swahili'),
 (u'ta', u'Tamil'),
 (u'te', u'Telugu'),
 (u'th', u'Thai'),
 (u'tr', u'Turkish'),
 (u'tt', u'Tatar'),
 (u'udm', u'Udmurt'),
 (u'uk', u'Ukrainian'),
 (u'ur', u'Urdu'),
 (u'vi', u'Vietnamese'),
 (u'zh-hans', u'Simplified Chinese'),
 (u'zh-hant', u'Traditional Chinese')]
LANGUAGES_BIDI  
[u'he', u'ar', u'fa', u'ur']
LANGUAGE_CODE   
'en-us'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE 
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    
u'django_language'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH    
u'/'
LOCALE_PATHS    
[]
LOGGING 
{'disable_existing_loggers': False,
 'formatters': {'simple': {'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                           'format': '[%(levelname)-7s] %(asctime)s - %(message)s'},
                'verbose': {'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                            'format': '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(process)d - %(thread)d - %(filename)s - %(message)s'}},
 'handlers': {'console': {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                          'formatter': 'verbose',
                          'level': 'DEBUG'},
              'fat_app_logfile': {'backupCount': 8,
                                  'class': 'cloghandler.ConcurrentRotatingFileHandler',
                                  'filename': '/var/log/fat/fat-log.txt',
                                  'formatter': 'verbose',
                                  'level': 'DEBUG',
                                  'maxBytes': 1048576},
              'rq_app_logfile': {'backupCount': 8,
                                 'class': 'cloghandler.ConcurrentRotatingFileHandler',
                                 'filename': '/var/log/fat/fat-log.txt',
                                 'formatter': 'verbose',
                                 'level': 'DEBUG',
                                 'maxBytes': 1048576}},
 'loggers': {'MainLogger': {'handlers': ['console', 'fat_app_logfile'],
                            'level': 'DEBUG',
                            'propagate': True},
             'django_auth_ldap': {'handlers': ['console', 'fat_app_logfile'],
                                  'level': 'DEBUG',
                                  'propagate': True},
             'rq_scheduler': {'handlers': ['console', 'fat_app_logfile'],
                              'level': 'DEBUG',
                              'propagate': True}},
 'version': 1}
LOGGING_CONFIG  
u'logging.config.dictConfig'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  
'/'
LOGIN_URL   
u'/accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL 
None
LOG_FILENAME    
'fat-log.txt'
LOG_FILES_ROTATE_NUM    
8
LOG_FILE_FULL_PATH  
'/var/log/fat/fat-log.txt'
LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE_MB    
1
MANAGERS    
[]
MEDIA_ROOT  
u''
MEDIA_URL   
u''
MESSAGE_STORAGE 
u'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
MIDDLEWARE  
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'config.nocache.NoCache']
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES  
[u'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 u'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware']
MIGRATION_MODULES   
{}
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT    
u'F j'
NUMBER_GROUPING 
0
PASSWORD_HASHERS    
u'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS 
u'********************'
PREPEND_WWW 
False
PROJECT_PATH    
'/home/yanayt/dev/fat/fatsite'
ROOT_URLCONF    
'config.urls'
RQ_QUEUES   
{'default': {'USE_REDIS_CACHE': 'default'},
 'scheduled_jobs': {'USE_REDIS_CACHE': 'default'}}
SECRET_KEY  
u'********************'
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER   
False
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF 
False
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  
False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS 
0
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER 
None
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT  
[]
SECURE_SSL_HOST 
None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT 
False
SERVER_EMAIL    
u'root@localhost'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS 
'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE  
1209600
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   
None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY 
True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME 
u'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH 
u'/'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   
False
SESSION_ENGINE  
'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE 
False
SESSION_FILE_PATH   
None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST  
False
SESSION_SERIALIZER  
u'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
SETTINGS_MODULE 
'config.settings'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT   
u'm/d/Y P'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT   
u'm/d/Y'
SIGNING_BACKEND 
u'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS  
[]
SIMPLE_LINE_FORMAT  
'[%(levelname)-7s] %(asctime)s - %(message)s'
SITE_ROOT   
'/home/yanayt/dev/fat/fatsite'
STATICFILES_DIRS    
['/home/yanayt/dev/fat/fatsite/static']
STATICFILES_FINDERS 
[u'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 u'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
STATICFILES_STORAGE 
u'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT 
'/var/www/static'
STATIC_URL  
'/static/'
TEMPLATES   
[{'APP_DIRS': True,
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': ['/home/yanayt/dev/fat/fatsite/templates',
           '/home/yanayt/dev/fat/fatsite/static'],
  'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS    
[]
TEST_RUNNER 
u'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
u','
TIME_FORMAT 
u'P'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
[u'%H:%M:%S', u'%H:%M:%S.%f', u'%H:%M']
TIME_ZONE   
'UTC'
USE_ETAGS   
False
USE_I18N    
True
USE_L10N    
True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
False
USE_TZ  
True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST    
False
USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT    
False
VERBOSE_LINE_FORMAT 
'%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(process)d - %(thread)d - %(filename)s - %(message)s'
WSGI_APPLICATION    
'config.wsgi.application'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS 
u'SAMEORIGIN'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT   
u'F Y'
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard page generated by the handler for this status code.
```

The new model is functional (we can drill into it in the admin", while the old one appears but we cannot drill into it.

How is it possible to get rid of the old model display in the admin? Where does Django gets the information from if it doesn't appear in the code/DB.

Thanks

Comment: admin.py under your app folder is responsible for displaying the tables. Edit the same and your problem will be resolved.

Comment: Just for clarification: the old app (directory), `reports`, does not have any `admin.py` file under it, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `admin.py` you are declaring the models that will register with the admin. Check there and remove it!

Comment: admin.py of the old model was totally deleted, but still appears (as in the screenshot)...

Comment: could you please post the `jira_fat/admin.py` file contents? Maybe its inside there...

Comment: Sure, I've added it to the question's body.

Comment: Question 1: what do you get if you click on the old model? 404 or 500 page? Question 2: Have you tried loading the same page from a different browser?

Comment: Answer 1: we get error 500.
Answer 2: Yes. Tried from a different browser, same behavior.

Comment: Could you please post the traceback from the 500 error? Not here in the comments, but edit your question and post it there!

Comment: OK. Last though: Have you removed your old app from your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Thanks @nik_m, but
no, I haven't remove it because aside from the models.py which was removed there is still much business-logic which require the app to remain in the INSTALLED_APPS.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the the DB table django-content-type contained both the old-model and the new one.
So 2 actions were required:

1. Update the auth_permission table to point to the new model entry in the django-content-type table.
2. Remove the old model entry in the django-content-type table.

Cheers